# What will happen when i set display:block to table

Tags: html, css

Why border-spacing and border-collapse is still working even if I set display property of table element to block. I think these properties will only work when display is table but I have changed it to block but still working. Why?

I am not expecting the border spacing to work.

Here is the code:

```css
    #tab {
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .row {
      display: table-row;
    }

    .data {
      display: table-cell;
      border: 2px solid;
    }

    table {
      border: 2px solid;
      display: block;
    }

    td,
    tr {
      display: block;
      padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tab">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="data">Lorem, ipsum.</div>
      <div class="data">Lorem, ipsum.</div>
    </div>
</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Changing the display property does not stop it still being a table.

Comment: Border-spacing is an inherited property, so the anonymous box created for the table adopts the border-spacing value even though it's not applied to the table element's principal box.

Comment: @Alohci deserve to be an answer, searched everywhere and couldn't find anything ...

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to understand if we visualize [the CSS box tree](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#intro).

Let's start with the basic HTML table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
    <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first thing to note is that the HTML parser will automatically wrap the tr element in a tbody element, so the DOM document is identical to that created from

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Adding the relevant borders and border-spacing CSS gives us our first snippet:

```html
<table border style="border-spacing:1em">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now we can construct what the DOM document and the Box Tree look like. Note that the CSS Tables level 3 draft specification says that [the border-spacing property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables-3/#border-spacing-property) applies to "table grid boxes when border-collapse is separate"

[image: DOM and Box tree - the table element creates the table wrapper box and table grid box]

If the table element is set to `display:block', we can see that the displayed table doesn't change.

```html
<table border style="border-spacing:1em; display:block">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What's happening is that the table element no longer creates the table wrapper box and table grid box, just a regular block box. But the CSS table structure is no longer complete, so CSS automatically creates the missing pieces to complete it. This means that the box tree ends up almost identical to the first case, just by a different route:

[image: DOM and Box tree - the tbody element causes an anonymous table grid box to be created to repair the table structure]

`border-spacing` is an inherited property, so it is assigned to the block container box, and the anonymous table grid box inherits the value and applies it.

---

Note that if all the table and a table-internal elements are set to `display:block` the border-spacing does not apply:

```css
table, table * {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table border style="border-spacing:1em">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

because the table structure no longer exists at all and there's no need for CSS to create the anonymous table grid box.

[image: DOM and Box tree - all the elements just create a single block box]